# Is it possible to crop a repeating background image?

Tags: css

The image expand from top to bottom in a floated div, I would like to crop the top and bottom of the repeating background image by 20 pixels from the top bar, and from the bottom bar.

```
.container {
    background:url(dot.gif) repeat-y;
    background-size:1px 1px;
}
```

I tried the following but this didn't help:

```
background-position:center 20px;
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why don't you make the container smaller?

Comment: I don't see any top or bottom bars.

Comment: Best bet would be to place another DIV inside the container and give it margin top and bottom 20px (or set padding top and bottom on the parent) then set the BG in that element.

Comment: I’m using liquid layout, I cannot make the container smaller.

Answer (score 0):

either make the container smaller by 20px or reduce the image by 20 px;
to make the container smaller by 20px
try to do that with jQuery

for the image try this

```
height://reduce by 20px;
width:auto;
```